# Provisioning Terraform Cloud Build Triggers build step to GCP project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

In my development, I'm testing if there's a way to replicate cloudbuild.yaml build steps (Terraform) to a TerraForm Cloud Build Trigger Build>Step resource. I have as followed

```
resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "build-trigger" {
provider = google-beta 
project = var.project
 github { 
      owner = "github repo"
      name = var.name
    push {
        branch = var.branch
    }
}

build {
    step {

      id = "branch name"
      name = "alpine"
      entrypoint = "sh"
      env = [
      {
          BRANCH_NAME = var.branch
    }
      args = [ "-c" ,  "echo ${BRANCH_NAME}" ]
         }
  




 } 
    
   description = "Push to any branch"
   filename = "cloudbuild.yaml"
}
```

```yaml
steps:
- id: 'branch name'
  name: 'alpine'
  entrypoint: 'sh'  
  args: 
  - '-c'
  - | 
      echo "***********************"
      echo "$BRANCH_NAME"
      echo "***********************"

# #   #[start tf-init]
- id: 'tf init'
  name: 'hashicorp/terraform:0.13.0'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args: 
  - '-c'
  - |
      if [ -d "environments/$BRANCH_NAME/" ]; then
        cd environments/$BRANCH_NAME
        terraform init
      else
        for dir in environments/*/
        do 
          cd ${dir}   
          env=${dir%*/}
          env=${env*/}
          echo ""
          echo "*************** TERRAFORM INIT ******************"
          echo "******* At environment: ${env} ********"
          echo "*************************************************"
          terraform init || exit 1
          cd ../../
        done
      fi 
  
# # [START tf-plan]
- id: 'tf plan'
  name: 'hashicorp/terraform:0.13.0'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args: 
  - '-c'
  - | 
      if [ -d "environments/$BRANCH_NAME/" ]; then
        cd environments/$BRANCH_NAME
        terraform plan
        
      else
        for dir in environments/*/
        do 
          cd ${dir}   
          env=${dir%*/}
          env=${env*/}  
          echo ""
          echo "*************** TERRAFOM PLAN ******************"
          echo "******* At environment: ${env} ********"
          echo "*************************************************"
          terraform plan  || exit 1
          cd ../../
        done
      fi 
  
 #  # [END tf-plan]

# #[START tf-apply]
- id: 'tf apply'
  name: 'hashicorp/terraform:0.13.0'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args: 
  - '-c'
  - | 
      if [ -d "environments/$BRANCH_NAME/" ]; then
        cd environments/$BRANCH_NAME      
        export TF_LOG=TRACE
        terraform apply -auto-approve 
      else
        echo "***************************** SKIPPING APPLYING *******************************"
        echo "Branch '$BRANCH_NAME' does not represent an oficial environment."
        echo "*******************************************************************************"
      fi

# [END tf-apply]
```

And Error I get is

```
On ../../modules/services/CloudBuildTriggers/cloudbuildtrig.tf line 22:
Expected a comma to mark the beginning of the next item.
```

How can I simply put bash commands in Build steps of cloud build triggers?
Or are they only reference to GCLOUD SDK commands?

Answer (score 2):

the Correct solution would be to not use {} and then use either EOF or EOT at the beginning and end of bash script.

```
 build {
    step {
      id          = "branch name"
      name        = "alpine"
      entrypoint  = "sh"
      args        = [
        "-c",  
<<-EOF
  echo "***********************"
  echo "$BRANCH_NAME"
  echo "***********************"
EOF
      ]
    }
    step {
      id          = "tf init"
      name        = "hashicorp/terraform:0.13.0"
      entrypoint  = "sh"
      args        = [
        "-c",
<<-EOF
if [ -d "environments/$BRANCH_NAME/" ]; then
  cd environments/$BRANCH_NAME
  terraform init
else
  for dir in environments/*/
  do
      cd $dir  
      env=$dir%*/
      env=$env#*/
      echo ""
      echo "*************** TERRAFORM INIT ******************"
      echo "******* At environment: $env ********"
      echo "*************************************************"
      terraform init || exit 1
      cd ../../
  done
fi
EOF
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some info here [1] on running bash commands and here [2] to create and manage triggers.
On the other hand, you may ask on the terraform community [3] since it could help with the error message.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts

[2] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers

[3] https://www.terraform.io/community.html

Comment: Thank you, some missing information was build steps have to be separated by step {} with each step. Also, the cloud build triggers the build step when deploying with TerraForm. Creates build inline config.  Where { } are not parsed between TerraForm and GCP. 
The EOF or EOT here tag can be used either way.